# not able to pass value to a textarea field in a webpage using vba

Tags: vba, vbscript

I am writing a vba code to pass information to a form at our sharepoint. I was able to pass all values to all text field, except texarea field. Please help

I research it more, and found that textarea field is retaining the value passed to it, but it is not showing up on webpage.

My code is -

```
Sub Auth_Verification()

Dim URL1, a, URL,issue, AuthID

Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows
URLFound = False

URL = "******** share point link/new.aspx"
URL1 = "**********************web form link "

CHECK_URL   'function to check if URL already exists

If URLFound = True Then
objIE.Visible = True
WShell.AppActivate "Clinical Operations/Claims Inquiries: New Item"

For Each a In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If a.innertext = "New" Then
        a.Click
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
 Else
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate URL1
    Wait_Webpage
 End If

 AuthID = InputBox("Please enter Auth ID", "Auth ID")
 Issue = InputBox("Please enter the Issue/Description", "Issue / Description")
 objIE.Document.getElementbyID("ctl00_m_g_436ae49f_3d72_444a_82c3_b08d03ced67e_ctl00_ctl04_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField").Value = Product   'Product
 objIE.Document.getElementbyID("ctl00_m_g_436ae49f_3d72_444a_82c3_b08d03ced67e_ctl00_ctl04_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField").Value = "NA"      'DIV (Cosmos)
 objIE.Document.getElementbyID("ctl00_m_g_436ae49f_3d72_444a_82c3_b08d03ced67e_ctl00_ctl04_ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField").Value = ICN       'ICN (Claim id"
 objIE.Document.getElementbyID("ctl00_m_g_436ae49f_3d72_444a_82c3_b08d03ced67e_ctl00_ctl04_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDate").Value = CalendarDate       'Claim Received date
 objIE.Document.getElementbyID("ctl00_m_g_436ae49f_3d72_444a_82c3_b08d03ced67e_ctl00_ctl04_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice").Value = "Other (describe in Issue description field)"       'Action Requested


 '' this is the line where I am getting stuck
 objIE.Document.getElementbyID("ctl00_m_g_436ae49f_3d72_444a_82c3_b08d03ced67e_ctl00_ctl04_ctl06_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField").Value = Issue       'Issue Description

Set WShell = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
Set objIE = Nothing
Set objShellWindows = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

Webpage HTML for text area filed is -

```
    <TR>
    <TD nowrap="true" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel"><H3 class="ms-standardheader">
    <nobr>Issue Description<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span></nobr>
</H3></TD>
    <TD valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="400px">
    <!-- FieldName="Issue Description"
         FieldInternalName="Issue_x0020_Description"
         FieldType="SPFieldNote"
      -->
        <span dir="none">
    <span dir="ltr">
        <textarea name="ctl00$m$g_436ae49f_3d72_444a_82c3_b08d03ced67e$ctl00$ctl04$ctl06$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$TextField" rows="8" cols="20" id="ctl00_m_g_436ae49f_3d72_444a_82c3_b08d03ced67e_ctl00_ctl04_ctl06_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" title="Issue Description" class="ms-long" dir="none"></textarea>
        <input name="ctl00$m$g_436ae49f_3d72_444a_82c3_b08d03ced67e$ctl00$ctl04$ctl06$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$TextField_spSave" type="HIDDEN" id="ctl00_m_g_436ae49f_3d72_444a_82c3_b08d03ced67e_ctl00_ctl04_ctl06_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_spSave" />
    </span>
<script>if (browseris.ie5up && browseris.win32 && !IsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled()){RTE_ConvertTextAreaToRichEdit("ctl00_m_g_436ae49f_3d72_444a_82c3_b08d03ced67e_ctl00_ctl04_ctl06_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField", true, true, "", "1033", null, null, null, null, null,"FullHtml", "\u002fsites\u002fOHBS\u002fCAOMAdmin",null,null,null,null);}else{document.write("&nbsp;<br><SPAN class=ms-formdescription><a href='javascript:HelpWindowKey(\"nsfullrichtext\")'>Click for help about adding HTML formatting.</a></SPAN>&nbsp;<br>");};</script></span>
        Briefly describe claim processing issue(requested clinical team intervention)

    </TD>
</TR>
```

Comment: Is there anyone who can help..